# Uploading application to iTunes Store stalls

Tags: ios, xcode4, app-store-connect, uploading

So I'm ready to upload an update to one of my apps. Everything is correctly signed and verification passes. However when trying to upload the bundle to iTunes Store it just stalls at (in XCode Organizer): "Uploading your application to iTunes Store" or (in Application Loader): "Verifying assets with iTunes Store".

It just sits there and fans kick in, revealing a java process at 125% which ultimately need to be forced quit.

I remember this has happened before but at that time it resolved it self after some days.

Anyone knows what the problem might be? Has iTunes Connect/Store any known problems at this moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-installing XCode in combination with patient waiting made it work for me. Sorry for not being able to give a better answer. But some things with Apple is just a mystery and will forever stay so.